# Displaying blank page in browser after running simple testcase in qunit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, qunit

I am new to qunit.I am running simple testcase in qunit.but nothing is getting displayed on screen.

This is HTML Runner:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.14.0.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.14.0.js"></script>
  <script src="MyJsUnitTests.js"></script>
  <script src="MyJsSourceCode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is MyJsSourceCode.js

```
var ArthimeticOperations = {
    addTwoNumbers : function (number1, number2) {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}
```

This is  MyJsUnitTests.js

```
test('Addition Test', function () {
    strictEqual(ArthimeticOperations.addTwoNumbers(3, 5), 8, "Tested the addition functionality");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the source code and test code includes... my guess is that your tests start running before the source code is included in the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.14.0.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.14.0.js"></script>

  <!-- SWAP THESE TWO...
  <script src="MyJsUnitTests.js"></script>
  <script src="MyJsSourceCode.js"></script>

  Like so:
  -->
  <script src="MyJsSourceCode.js"></script>
  <script src="MyJsUnitTests.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```